# JPA OrderBy in @OneToMany by external field

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

I have entities:

```
@Entity
public class C {

 @Column
 private String name;

}


@Entity
public class B {

 @Column
 private Integer id;

 @ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name = "id_c")
 private C c;

}


@Entity
public class A {

 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "a")
 @OrderBy("id")
 private Set<B> itemsB;

}
```

Now when i access to A.itemsB() - items ordered by B.id

I need to get A.itemsB() ordered by C.name. Is this possible?

I tried to write something like @OrderBy("c.name") but it not work.

Comment: you use a QUERY, and put that as the ORDER BY

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/OrderBy.html

Answer (score 0):

just check wich Order is imported : org.hibernate.annotations.OrderBy or javax.persistence.OrderBy.. you should use the second.

Comment: Used javax.persistence.OrderBy, but @OrderBy("c.name") also not work.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use a 'Set<B>', but a 'List<B>'.Sets are always unordered.